# Is there a good way to use C# (.NET Framework) and Python code together?

Tags: python, c#, .net, integration

We have a solution written in C#/.NET Framework 4.7. It has a lot of infrastructure code related to environment configurations, database access, logging, exception handling etc.
Our co-workers are eager to contribute to the project with Python code that makes a lot of special calculations. Ideally we want to pass configuration plus (big amount of) input data to their code and get back (big amount of) results without resorting to database integration. Is there a viable way to do so? Main goals are: 1) not to rewrite Python code to C# 2) not to duplicate configuration/database related code in Python to make future maintenance easier

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally we want to pass configuration plus (big amount of) input data to their code and get back (big amount of) results [...]

So if all you do is want to pass parameters to a python script and get back the result, there is a pretty easy way to do so. I suggest you take a look at [IronPython](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3). Not only can you do that, but you can also easily import things from .NET/C# in your python scripts if there is ever a need for that.

Comment: not just some "parameters", rather data. Two-dimensional arrays containing thousands (maybe hundreds of thousands) elements. Doable?

Comment: At the end of the day, a two dimensional array is also just a data type in C# and can therefore be passed by using a method parameter. The amount of entries the 2-dimensional array also does not matter for this approach, it could have a size of 1 or 10.000. So yes, it is entirely possible. It is also pretty easy with the suggested IronPython. At first, it looks a little bit weird if you are not used to it, but the average developer will get the gist of it pretty quickly.

Comment: Are you saying that I can pass parameters/collections of any type between C# and IronPython code? If that's true, it may be exactly I'm looking for...

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. You can load a python script in C#, and you are also able to load .NET/C# things like classes and methods into python. All you do is to make sure that the passed parameters match the type and order of the method parameter list, because you have no checks for this (obviously).

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is exactly what Unix (e.g. Gnu/Linux) dose. The Unix philosophy is about creating many (usually small) programs (that usually do one thing well), and connecting them to create a system that is greater than the parts. To do this we use inter-process communication, usually pipelines / streams.

An alternate approach is to compile the C# into a library, that can be called form the python.